# how to terminate the session on submit?

Tags: php, html

my session should be terminated if someone presses the submit button, but it will not be deleted!

How do I need to change the following code for that?

This is my code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && isset($_SESSION['history'])) { 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter (email,timestamp,history) VALUES 
        ('$email','$timestamp','$history')";   
        if(mysqli_query($db,$sql) && mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
              session_start();
              session_unset();
              if(isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"])) {
                  setcookie("PHPSESSID","",time()-86400);
              }
              session_destroy();
         }    
}
```

This is a include 
file and this is the code where the file was included:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "zugrif.inc.php";
include "sessiontracker.inc.php";
include "historymaker.inc.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action='newsletter.php' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='email'>
  <input type='submit' value='Absenden'>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found the error I was looking for.

The problem was that I forgot a parameter of `mysqli_affected_rows`. The correct syntax is:

```
 mysqli_affected_rows($ db)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my php logout function:

```
function logout()
{


// unset any session variables
$_SESSION = array();

// expire cookie
if (!empty($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
{
    // setcookie(session_name(), "", time() - 42000);
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
            $params["path"], $params["domain"],
            $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
            );
}



// destroy session
session_destroy();

}
```

Comment: Now I found the error but the problem was that I forgot a parameter at mysqli_affected_rows () correctly it says mysqli_affected_rows ($ db) anyway thanks for the help